# .htaccess Redirect Subfolder to New Domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My client wants to use theirdomain.com/billpay to mask the URL given to us by the company who processes their online payments. I understand that it can be done via DNS if it's a subdomain (ie billpay.theirdomain.com), but I'm not sure how to go about it when it's an actual appendage of the main URL as stated above. I'm assuming this can be done via the .htaccess file. This is the code I have now, but I get a 500 internal server error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /croutlet/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /billpay(.*) /http://www.google.com/$1
```

Comment: Remove `/` before `http`: `RedirectMatch 301 /billpay(.*) http://www.google.com/$1`

Comment: Do you mean mask or do you mean redirect? The two are quite different. A redirect will take from yourdomain.com to theirdomain.com - masking will keep them on yourmdomain.com at all times.

Comment: @Bulk, if there is a way to mask it that would be best. However I was going to settle for a redirect.

Comment: @E.Peterson not in this case no I'm afraid, a redirect is your only real option.

Comment: @anubhava removing the forward slash still gives a 500 internal error.

Comment: Do you literally have `//301 Redirect Entire Directory` in your htaccess file?

Comment: It is always advisable to check your Apache error.log whenever you get 500

Comment: @JonLin, no I do not. I just noted it for Stackoverflow. I'm no longer getting a 500 error after clearing cache, but instead of going to google.com it's calling for the following page: mydomain.com/http:/www.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't what's affecting the 500 error, but try using only mod_rewrite instead of both mod_alias (the `RedirectMatch` directive) along with mod_rewrite. When you have routing rewrite rules, they kind of interfere with each other because both modules get applied to every request.

```
RewriteRule ^billpay(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /croutlet/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that because the redirect is a 301 (permanent), your browser will always cache the redirect unless you clear it.